# P0172 - System too rich

Tags: engine, fuel-trims, p0172

I have a P0172 on my 2011 L4 Camry. Summary of what I did:

- I saw the light on, and once I saw the code, I checked the air filter. It was filthy disgusting and completely disintegrated (rat/rodent infestation). The whole filer box was full of fuzz from the chewed-up filter and other stuff. Even the fire mesh (on top of the filter box) was ruptured.
- I changed the filter and cleaned the filter box, didn't solve it (erasing the codes didn't do much either).
- I then cleaned the MAF sensor with alcohol (and after forgetting to connect the wire and getting another error!) and erased the codes, the light went off for a day or so. It came back on the next day.
- I checked the codes again, and besides the codes that I got after forgetting the MAF sensor wires, and it's still P0172.
- I checked the live data with different RPMs, and the MAF sensor output seems to be right. around 4 (g/s) in idle and 15 in 2500 rpm.
- However, from the freeze frame data and both in idle and 2000 rpm, the oxygen sensor is giving me ~3V. It is my understanding that the voltage should be between 0.1 and 0.9, but here we are. Not much difference if I hit the gas and take the rpm to 3000.
- The car was in storage for ~2months, and had a dead battery, so the long term is not very longterm, but here are the freezeframe data:

| Q | V |
| --- | --- |
| RMP | 780 |
| MAF | 6.7 g/s |
| O2SB1S1 | 3.093V |
| Fuel system | CL |
| ECT | 85 C |
| STFT | -21% |
| LTFT | -34% |
| O2SB1S2 | 0.835 V |

- Live data at idle gives me same O2SB1S1, 0.055V for O2SB1S2, and -8% for STFT.

Any help on the diagnosis would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: ~3v or ~0.3v? Decimal point matters.  If its 0.3v then either the sensor is faulty or its operating correctly, measuring a lean condition with the engine computer richening fuel mixtures. Here's info on O2 sensor operation; https://www.aa1car.com/library/o2sensor.htm. P0172 can be as simple as replacing the O2 sensor or more complicated with additional diagnostics needed to examine every sensor of the EFI system with an errant one creating this rich running condition.

Comment: It's 3.0 V. I since found out that it is an AF sensor and ideally should be around 3.3V. But how where do I start the diagnosis? How do I find the faulty one?

Comment: My first guess is, you've got a stuck injector. @FDryer - I don't think the sensor is at fault here (or at least not directly). It is reading a high voltage, which is what it should be reading with a very rich condition. If the O2 was at fault, it would be reading a very low voltage, which would tell the ECU to dump more fuel into the cylinders. As it is, the ECU is trying to pull fuel out and it's still rich.

Comment: So cleaning or replacing the injector, right? Do you recommend seafoam intake cleaner, stp injector cleaner that goes in the gas, or taking out and cleaning?

Comment: Did you review how the upstream O2 sensor outputs between 0.1v-0.9v and not 3.3v? This presumes you're measuring the output signal. A leaking injector would/might lower fuel pressure and result in a dry black spark plug while the other three should show a tan color. Wet black plugs imply excessive oil burning.